# How to send a data from a table to a form in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm totally new to CI. I am working on the project that fetch data from a db and send it a particular data to a form on a click of a ADD button. Here is the screen shot of my table..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqOCr.png)

Here is the screenshot of my form..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUEzC.png)

Comment: That is not proper functionality. Same add functionality. but why multiple add button in your table form. Edit/Delete button only multiple button need and add button need only one common

Comment: Read [this article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) of how to ask properly, then add relevant code. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your add button should collect the data it needs, send it to controller, and controller passes it to model so it can collect the data that you need by sql. Pass it back to controller and controller passes the data to the view ( your form . In your view you just put the data where ever you need.